# Is there a way to call procedures with out parameters using sequelize ORM for NODEJS

Tags: node.js, oracle, orm, sequelize.js

```
**oracle procedure**
create or relace PROCEDURE sp_user( userStatusCondition IN varchar2, useResult OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
        IS
        BEGIN
        OPEN useResult FOR SELECT a.USERID,
        a.FIRSTNAME,
        a.LASTNAME,
        b.FIRSTNAME as reportingUserFirstName, 
        FROM USERS a
        left join employee b on  a.REPORUSERID=b.EXTERNALUSERID 
        where  a.STATUS = userStatusCondition
        ORDER BY a.CREATEDAT asc;
        END ;
```

**procedure call in Node **

```
let userStatusCondition="ACT"     
sql = 'BEGIN  sp_user(:userStatusCondition,:result); END;';
let options={}
const data = {userStatusCondition:userStatusCondition,result:{dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR}};
let output = await sequelize.query(sql, data, options);
```

```
**Error** 

ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

Need suggestions to call and retrieve data from  **oracle procedure** with **out paramater**  using **sequelize** ORM In **Nodejs**

Comment: Why do you assign `data` into an empty Object `{}`, when `data` already is an object itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sequelize, you can execute a pl/sql as a RAW query. We don't return cursor object for now in Sequelize. You can definitely raise a feature request in https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize, and we can add the feature eventually.

If a pl/sql doesn't involve a cursor as bind, you can execute it like I am doing in the code block below.

```
plsql = `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE no_proc
        (p_in IN VARCHAR2, p_inout IN OUT VARCHAR2, p_out OUT NUMBER)
      AS
      BEGIN
        p_inout := p_in || p_inout;
        p_out := 101;
      END;`

        await sequelize.query(plsql, {type: QueryTypes.RAW})
plsql = `BEGIN
          no_proc(:i, :io, :o);
         END;`
await sequelize.query(plsql, {bind: {
        i:  'Chris',
        io: { val: 'Jones', dir: oracledb.BIND_INOUT },
        o:  { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT }
      },type: QueryTypes.RAW} )
```